# TLE to HOTELS (spoj)

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am doing a problem of spoj i tried to do it but I am always getting TLE(time limit expired )
the question is [Hotels](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/HOTELS/) . this is my code , please can you tell me the way to optimize it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int a,b,i;
    scanf("%llu %llu",&a,&b);
    unsigned long long int arr[a];
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        scanf("%llu",&arr[i]);
    }


        unsigned long long int d;
        unsigned long long int k,z=0;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        d = arr[i];
        for(k=i+1;k<a+1;k++)
        {
            if (d<b)
            {
                if(z<d)
                z = d;
            }
            else
            if(d==b)
            {
                z = d;
                break;
            }
            else
            break;
            d = d + arr[k];
        }
        if(d==b)
        break;
    }
    printf("%llu",z);
    return 0;
}
```

in this like if input 5 12  , these five are 2 1 3 4 5 to make 12 then i do like this :
first i compare 12 with 2 , then 2+1 , then 2+1+3 and so on after it goes to 5 it compares 12 to 1 , 1+3 , 1+3+4 .. and in this way i am taking only consecutive and break when i find equal to 12 otherwise it goes on till last.

Hitesh

Comment: Voting to close. There is no question of any substance here. The author has not made any effort to explain what the problem is and is assumming we can read her mind. I throw my hands up...

Comment: The key to solving this quickly is that the hotels you choose must be *consecutive* in the input list.

Comment: @jerry i have choosen consecutive ,

Comment: @hitesh_jhamb: I'll take your word for it. That didn't seem immediately obvious (to me) from your code -- though I'll admit I didn't follow your code very well at all. Perhaps variable names a little more meaningful than `d`, `b`, `z`, etc., would help. A quick check with what seemed like the simplest, most obvious possible code certainly didn't set a speed record, but did finish within the time allotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to restart again as you said in the explanation `after it goes to 5 it compares 12 to 1 , 1+3 , 1+3+4 .. and in this way`. Look at your approach carefully, you are recalculating the sums of a subarray again and again. For e.g - You have already calculated sum of subarray `1+3+4` when you were doing `2+1+3+4`. Hence there is still some scope of optimization.

Before telling the exact solution, I want you to try it out first. Also as one more hint refer to the following problem [Find subarray with given sum](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/19267).

**EDIT:** Sharing complete solution for future purpose.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/* Returns the maximum possible sum less than or equal to the gieven sum */
int subArraySum(int arr[], int n, int sum)
{
    /* Initialize curr_sum as value of first element
     and starting point as 0 */
    int curr_sum = arr[0], max_sum = 0, start = 0, i;

    /* Add elements one by one to curr_sum and if the curr_sum exceeds the
     sum, then remove starting element */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        // If curr_sum exceeds the sum, then remove the starting elements
        while (curr_sum > sum && start < i-1)
        {
            curr_sum = curr_sum - arr[start];
            start++;
        }

        //keep track of the maximum sum so far.
        if (max_sum < curr_sum)
            max_sum = curr_sum;

        curr_sum = curr_sum + arr[i];
    }

    return max_sum;
}
```

// Driver program to test above function

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {7, 3, 5, 6};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int sum = 9;
    printf("Max Sum = %d\n", subArraySum(arr, n, sum));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks , finally i got it accepted with  the link you provided me

Comment: I also tried to submit and successfully got the 14th rank. What about yours?

Comment: well i got 141, what else do you do to get it in 0.14 sec i got in 0.85

Comment: add an if construct to check if the curr_sum==sum in the start of the loop. will reduce iterations.